# How to create a SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, jboss5.x

I'm trying to create a **SSL** certificate for **Jboss5**, but the same questions are asked to me several times, and I don't know why. Can someone help me please ?

[image]

Comment: What is your question? That is one of many ways to create a self sign certificate.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @rekire I want to know why the questions are asked several times

Comment: I am still not sure if I understood you correctly. You mean why there are 8 questions? Or does that repeat endless for you? If you want why there are those questions that is simple: Those are typically fields you need to fill out. That is the distinguished name in short DN which you find in every x509 certificate.

Comment: I have find my error. In fact, my interface is in french. when i enter **yes** to the last question it can't work. But when i enter **oui** it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad that we got this issue fixed :)